# Have a flexbox next to another flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have two flex boxes with child elements. I wish each of these flex boxes to take up 50% of the page.

```
<div class="flexbox">
    ....
</div>
<div class="flexbox">
    ....
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
.flexbox{
    display:flex;
    width: 50%;
    ....
```

I have also thought about wrapping both divs in a container, and displaying flex on the container with a basis of 50%. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it without a container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this result you need to:

1. Use `display: inline-flex` on `.flexbox` elements
2. Remove white-space from HTML
3. Use `box-sizing: border-box` for paddings and borders

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.flexbox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    ....
</div><div class="flexbox">
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: @panthro Is that a question or statement? `:)`

Comment: A bit of both :p, think its a whitespce issue, how do I remove it?

Comment: You literally remove white space between divs in html like i did in answer.

Comment: Yes there are couple of ways to remove white space but i this case i suggest this one or with comments.